# Alternate RowStyle in ListBox itemtemplate: Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

In our Windows Phone project, we have a ListBox ItemTemplate. Where we are binding some data. And while displaying the data we want every alternate row to be highlighted. Like below... Can somebody help, how I could achieve this.

Row1

***Row2***

Row3

***Row4***

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
       <Grid>
         <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Calibri" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
            <HyperlinkButton xml:space="preserve" Foreground="Black" FontSize="4"></HyperlinkButton>
         </StackPanel>                             
       </Grid>                            
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

The item list I am binding this data source comes out to be like this

```
   public static readonly IList<String> Metrics = 
            new ReadOnlyCollection<string>
                          (new List<String> { 
                                                    "ATM not working",
                                                    "Store out of business",
                                                    "ATM not there",
                                                    "Wrong store Address",
                                                    "Wrong store Name",
                                                    "Wrong ATM features Listed"
                                              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution (probably not the best) may be to make a property in your Item class for BackgroundBrush then you can assign any brush to your Background:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <Grid Background={Binding BackBrush}>
         <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="32" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="Calibri" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></TextBlock>
           <HyperlinkButton xml:space="preserve" Foreground="Black" FontSize="4"></HyperlinkButton>
         </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Then your item class can look like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush BackBrush { get; set; }
}
```

and you an example item:

```
yourItemSource.Add(new Item { Text = "First", BackBrush = (App.Current as App).Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush});
```

As you have a ReadOnlyCollection you can make your ItemsSource like this:

```
myList.ItemsSource = Metrics.Select((a, b) => new Item { Text = a, BackBrush = b % 2 == 0 ? (App.Current as App).Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush : new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent) }).ToList();
```

This probably needs some improvements but should work.

Comment: Thanks I have added in the question my Itemsource that I am binding to the Grid. Can you help me how could I prepare Metrics parameter as itemsource.

Comment: @Subhamoy I've added one possible solution how you can assign your `Metrics` along with BackgroundBrush. Don't forget to add `using System.Linq`